# c# mail script failing on HTML content

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm putting together a script to send out a preview html mail to hotmail etc, and I utlising an existing script - I'm new to c# so this is as much a learning expereince forme too.

The problem is I have made a few ammends, and it's fine up to the point I drop HTML source into the comments box - it then fails the sending.

I have looked into it and tried changing the new MailMessage(); to new MailDefinition(); and also adding in faqMsg.IsBodyHtml = true; but it's still failing. it's fine just on regular text. Any thoughts what I need to look into ?

```
SmtpClient smtpCli = new SmtpClient("localhost");
MailMessage faqMsg = new MailMessage();
//MailDefinition faqMsg = new MailDefinition();

//faqMsg.BodyFileName = "email.htm";  
//faqMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
faqMsg.From = new MailAddress("");
faqMsg.To.Add("");
faqMsg.Subject = "Mail test :" + subject.Text;

//Plain Text part
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Enquiry Type:" + enquirytype.SelectedValue + "\r\nFrom:" + "\r\nEmail:" + email.Text + "\r\n\r\nComments\r\n" + comments.Text + "\r\n[EOF]", null, "text/plain");
//HTML part

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<strong>Enquiry Type:</strong>" + enquirytype.SelectedValue + "<br><br><strong>Email:</strong>" + email.Text + "<br><br><hr><br><strong>Comments</strong><br>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(comments.Text) + "<br>EOF", null, "text/html");
faqMsg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
faqMsg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

//Add Header Markers
faqMsg.Headers.Add("X-Company", "");
faqMsg.Headers.Add("X-Location", "");
faqMsg.Headers.Add("X-Brand", "");

smtpCli.Send(faqMsg);
lbReport.Text = "Your Message was Sent";
//Response.Redirect("email-thanks.aspx");
```

Comment: Could you clarify "it then fails the sending"? Is there an exception thrown? If so, could you include some information about it?

Comment: It's a bit tough to specify the exact message because where I work we have these one generic error message - with no friendly error messages.

So all I have to go on is the mail sends fine when I fill out the details, and a mail drops into my mailbox - but as soon as I drop some HTML tags in the comments field (my intention is to drop a whole html email in there to test) such as <p>hello</p> etc it throws up our generic fail message. Aplogies - I know it's not much to work on without specific errors.

Comment: If you have the code, can you step through it and see what the real error is?

Answer (score 0):

Hey, what error are you getting?

Looking at the code, you may need to add an @ symbol before any strings with the \ inside. But that's a guess without the error.

Comment: I'm kind of working int he dark due to this company specific error screen message. It's the same for everything, just a page fail. What I do know is soon as I put something in that resembles a tag, the page breaks. ie < is fine <p it breaks, but lines and lines of regular text no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact exception text you are seeing, Im going to take a stab at this.

This doesn't sound like an email error.

this sounds like the generic error that won't allow you to enter HTML content into a textbox.

Be sure `VaildateRequest=false` in the `@Page` attribute at the top of the page.